# How to respresent 3D (x y z) value as a single value?

Tags: libsvm, representation, data-representation

How can i represent a 3D coordinate as a singular value?

I need this since the libsvm requieres the input data to be 1-dimensional?

Thank you

Comment: What is the range and resolution of your x, y, z coördinates ?

Comment: the range in all directions is -10 to 10. The values are stored as floats, with max 7 decimal points but i think i can work with less fine grained data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use 3 features for each coordinate. (They even write so in their README)

Comment: in the guide it does indeed say so (they give an example with RGB values), but that format 1:{1,0,0} 2:{0,0,1} etc.. is not accepted by checkdata.py in /tools. Moreover, my data is 3D float values and not discrete. Have you accomplished this? I would love to know`!

Comment: I meant: instead of one 3-tupel, you write 3 1-tupel. Like: {1:0, 2:1, 3:1} for the RGB value (1, 1, 1).

Comment: Just saw jou explicitly asked for a single value representation in the title - Answer: you don't need it.

Comment: so a sequence would become: 1:{1:1.354 2:3.535 3:4.37} 2:{1:0.78 2:2.975 3:6.78} 3:.....etc.? can't check it now cos my system is being trained on another dataset (for another 5 days).

Comment: no, just {1:1.354, 2:3.535, 3:4.37, 4:0.78, 5:2.9 ...} - it's totally fine when the values are separated.